# Custom puppet provider: How to retrieve a file from puppet master

Tags: ruby, puppet, custom-type

I need to retrieve a static file from within a custom Puppet provider from Puppet master (just like file built-in resource does). Defining a separate built-in file resource in Puppet code is not an option. So, in Puppet code the thing should look like this:

```
custom_type{
  property1 => 'value1'
  property2 => 'value2'
  file => "puppet:///${module_name}/somefile"
}
```

Although I've written custom types and providers before, interaction with Puppet master's file server is something I do not get.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `file` type after all. You need not do this from the manifest level. Puppet can handle this using *generated resources*.

For example, the [nagios types](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/8e495a199cac9723859727ec0bc0f67ec4b517b2/lib/puppet/util/nagios_maker.rb#L19-26) do something similar.

In your custom type code, introduce a `generate` hook.

```
def generate
  if self[:file]
    Puppet::Type.type(:file).new({
      :name   => <whatever the path on the agent is>,
      :ensure => :present,
      :source => self[:file],
    })
  end
end
```

The agent takes care of adding this resource to the catalog.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [puppet file type](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file/source.rb), it looks like this is what you want on line 103:

```
 Puppet::FileServing::Content.indirection.find(metadata.source, :environment => resource.catalog.environment_instance, :links => resource[:links])
```

`metadata.source` is the path to the file.